# Cannot find ApplicationView in UWP

Tags: c#, visual-studio, uwp

First of all im started to work with UWP today for the first time.

And i can´t seem to find the "ApplicationView" Setting im trying to add the following snippet to my MainPage constructor:

```
public MainPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();

    ApplicationView.PreferredLaunchViewSize = new Size(480, 800);
    ApplicationView.PreferredLaunchWindowingMode = ApplicationViewWindowingMode.PreferredLaunchViewSize;

    // if you want not to have any window smaller than this size...
    ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().SetPreferredMinSize(new Size(480, 800));
}
```

[image: this is what Visual Studio 2017 tells me]

Comment: Just place the cursor point on `red underlines` and the IDE will let you know the actual problem.

Comment: ok thanks that was so stupid I was missing the "using Windows.UI.ViewManagement;"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just need to add the needed namespace : Windows.UI.ViewManagement at the top of you file.

```
using Windows.UI.ViewManagement;
```

`ApplicationView` ìs defined in the [Windows.UI.ViewManagement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.ViewManagement.ApplicationView) namespace